# Consilidating multiple Hadoop clusters

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

We have multiple hadoop cluster using hive and pig, what is the best way to consolidate them in to one? In BI this was done by build EDW or MDM approach. how about hadoop is any one thinking about this

Answer (score 0):

Pig and Hive are client side libraries, so there is nothing to migrate for them. Only the Pig and Hive client have to point to the appropriate Hadoop clusters.

Regarding the data, you could use [DistCp](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/distcp.html) to move the data across clusters.